# Error debugging PySpark after upgrading cluster's Databricks Runtime

Tags: python, pyspark, azure-databricks, databricks-connect

I have updated an Azure Databricks cluster from runtime 5.5LTS to 7.3LTS. Now I'm getting an error when I debug in VSCode. I have updated my Anaconda connection like this:

```sh
> conda create --name dbconnect python=3.7
> conda activate dbconnect
> pip uninstall pyspark
> pip install -U databricks-connect==7.3.*
> databricks-connect configure
> databricks-connect test
```

So far so good, but now I'm trying to debug the following

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
setting = spark.conf.get("spark.master")

if "local" in setting:
    from pyspark.dbutils import DBUtils
    dbutils = DBUtils(spark.sparkContext)
```

On the `dbutils = DBUtils(spark.sparkContext)`, it throws an exception

> Exception has occurred: AttributeError 'SparkContext' object has no
> attribute 'conf'

I have tried creating the `conf`

```
from pyspark.dbutils import DBUtils
import pyspark
conf = pyspark.SparkConf()
pyspark.SparkContext.getOrCreate(conf=conf)
dbutils = DBUtils(spark.sparkContext)
```

but I still get the same error. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the docs [Access DBUtils](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/databricks-connect.html#access-dbutils), you need to pass the SparkSession `spark` not the SparkContext :

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.dbutils import DBUtils

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

dbutils = DBUtils(spark)
```